# Anything in Scala equivalent to C#'s `dynamic`?

Tags: scala, dynamic

I believe the answer is no, but wouldn't hurt to check: anything in Scala that's equivalent to C#'s [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword? Anything on the horizon?

I know about scala.Dynamic, which is not the same thing - in C# you don't know the types at compile time, and the dynamic type propagates.

I also know about invokedynamic, which is not the same thing - invokedynamic is the infrastructure that would make language constructs like `dynamic` performant.

Anything on the horizon?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is: objects extending the Dynamic trait behave similarly to variables declared as dynamic in C#.

This is a new feature in Scala 2.9 (but still considered experimental), see the scaladoc at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic.

Comment: I missed the part in your post where you said you know about scala.Dynamic. You're correct in that it isn't quite the same as the dynamic keyword.